# How to hack an input field to fire md-datepicker when I click on it

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

How can I turn an input text to fire md-datepicker ? and get something like this:
[image: wanted result]

Comment: use `md-datepicker` instead of an `input` may be?

Comment: Well there is an issue related to using md-datepicker inside md-input-container... so sadly I need to hack this to continue my work, I can guide you to an opened ticket regarding this issue if you are interested

Comment: okay can you show me the open issue. Also have a look at this [demo](https://material.angularjs.org/latest/demo/datepicker).

Comment: https://github.com/angular/material/issues/4233 currently you can use it with md-input-container but with no label / placeholder to not get confusing results... basically it's unusable

Comment: This has been fixed in v1.1.4, here have a look at this working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2vtsaywx/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use md-input-container and md-datepicker and customize the skin with classes. Hope this helps..

```
<div class="form-group form-group-sm row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div ng-class="{ 'has-error': ....}">
            <label for="startDate" class="required-field">Start Date</label>
            <md-input-container class="custom-md-container">
                <md-datepicker class="customDatePicker" id="startDate" md-placeholder="Start Date" name="startDate" md-open-on-focus="true" ng-model=".." required></md-datepicker>
            </md-input-container>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: maybe my question was on the short side, I tried this but there is a current bug in datepicker you can't use it inside an md-input-container & add labels to it because you will get confusing results:
http://imgur.com/EQXgmVU